# What's the meaning of "fed" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I found this sentence in a novel. I'm quite sure I understand the general meaning, but I can't understand the exact meaning of "fed". It should be the simple past of "feed", but in the dictionary I can't find a definition that can help me.

Two men are moving a piano.

> The taller guy held it in place atop the padded board while his partner ran thick nylon straps into slots in the board and **fed them through to the other side**. Each strap went over the piano and was buckled tightly to itself.

Comment: See definition 3 here:  https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/feed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put something through something else. Imagine someone putting on a belt, how the belt passes through the loops. Imagine shoe laces being fed through the a new pair of shoes, or thread passing through a needle. Imagine paper being fed through a printer. In that sentence, the taller guy is putting straps around the piano, buckling it, so that it can be carried.

Comment: +1 You might add that it's a metaphor: passing something through an opening is like putting food in your mouth, or feeding a baby.

Comment: ***Ropes or lines*** are said to be fed through openings or slots or loops. And for shoes, I don't think I would use feed.